# longjmp,setjmp 's infinite loop

Tags: c, linux, signals

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static jmp_buf env_alrm;

static void sig_alarm(int signo)
{
        longjmp(env_alrm, 1); 
}
int sleep2(unsigned int seconds)
{
        if(signal(SIGALRM, sig_alarm)==SIG_ERR)
                return seconds;

        if(setjmp(env_alrm)==0) //when it is first called, return value is 0
        {
                alarm(seconds);
                pause();
        }

        return (alarm(0))
}
```

On this code, I think this is making infinite loop. My thinkings are following:

We call `sleep2()`functions in main like `sleep2(3)`, then after calling `pause()`, `SIGALRM` will be delivered after 3 secs. So, signal handler `sig_alarm()` will be called.

And, after calling `longjmp()`, it will go to `setjmp()` function in sleep2. And finally, after testing `setjmp()`'s return value(which should be 1 after calling `longjmp()`) it will execute `return alarm(0)`. So, it will immediately call `sig_alarm()` again(because `SIGALRM` is delivered again), and this loop will be continued.

What am I missing?

Comment: Use `siglongjmp` in a signal handler. But read [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) first to understand that you should not.

Comment: The result of alarm is the number of seconds remaining.  If there are 0 seconds remamining, just return 0 instead of alarm(0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`alarm(0)` does not deliver any alarm event. It cancels a previously scheduled alarm and returns the number of seconds remaining until this canceled alarm (if any).

The last line of your code does not cause infinite loop, because it does not execute `sig_alarm`. It returns the number of seconds remaining to a normal expiration of your `sleep2`. In your small example this will be zero. Your code is probably a part of larger software where `longjmp` (and the last line of your `sleep2`) may be executed before the timer expires. In this case `sleep2` returns the number of seconds remaining to a normal expiration.